# R Count Total Time from occurences of event

Tags: r

Here is my dataframe with `dput` function .

```
structure(list(Time.stamp = structure(1:34, .Label = c("00:07:00", 
"00:12:00", "00:18:00", "00:23:00", "00:28:00", "00:33:00", "00:38:00", 
"00:43:00", "00:48:00", "00:53:00", "00:58:00", "01:03:00", "01:08:00", 
"01:13:00", "01:18:00", "01:23:00", "01:28:00", "01:33:00", "01:38:00", 
"01:43:00", "01:48:00", "01:53:00", "01:58:00", "02:03:00", "02:08:00", 
"02:13:00", "02:18:00", "02:23:00", "02:28:00", "02:33:00", "02:38:00", 
"02:43:00", "02:48:00", "02:53:00"), class = "factor"), Battery.Voltage = c(54.5205, 
54.5205, 54.4447, 54.5205, 43, 44, 45, 46, 54.5205, 54.5205, 
41, 54.5205, 43, 54.5205, 54.5205, 54.5205, 54.5205, 54.5205, 
54.5205, 54.5205, 54.5205, 54.5205, 54.5205, 54.5205, 54.5205, 
54.5205, 54.5205, 54.5205, 45, 54.5205, 54.5205, 54.5205, 54.5205, 
46), Power = c(5997.756589, 6179.146292, 6144.672398, 6071.506469, 
6059.550123, 6021.680184, 6071.501017, 6047.588326, 6005.727486, 
6011.708385, 6019.881107, 6161.209048, 5993.592688, 6011.713837, 
5977.823894, 6053.569224, 6091.433712, 6005.727486, 5991.781142, 
6041.612879, 6001.747489, 6015.693833, 5981.809342, 6065.52557, 
6053.569224, 5997.756589, 5981.814794, 6003.737487, 6061.540122, 
6011.702933, 6013.698383, 6019.684734, 6081.472816, 5969.847545
), f_device_time_date = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "01/02/2017", class = "factor"), 
    Condition = structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
    2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L), .Label = c("No", 
    "Yes"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("Time.stamp", "Battery.Voltage", 
"Power", "f_device_time_date", "Condition"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-34L))
```

My question is:
I want to count the longest repeating No, grouping by dates dates.

I want to output the table as

```
Date                 Max_duration of condition No

01-02-2017            9
02-02-2017            5
```

etc.

My approach:
Used rle function to count longest duration of NO and Yes. 
Note: I only need longest No on each day.

```
round_length = rle(data1$battery_test)
data1 %>% group_by(f_device_time_date) %>% tapply(round_length$lengths,round_length$values,max)

output: 
Error in match.fun(FUN) : 
  'round_length$values' is not a function, character or symbol
```

Any help deeply appreciated.

Comment: Please `dput` your data.frame and share as part of question. It will help others to respond quickly.

Comment: I have dput the data.frame. Thanks for your comment

Comment: What do you mean by ` longest repeating No,`? Do you want to count number repeating number of dates with `Yes` and `NO`?

Comment: Yes I want longest repeating No across dates.. thanks

Comment: Then the solution provided by me should work for you. Try it and let me know please.

Comment: Thanks MKR,  Output : Warning message:
All formats failed to parse. No formats found. There will be some problem in Unite

Comment: Did you tried on sample data provided by you? Did it worked on that? If yes then only issue it cannot run on your real data is that format of date/time (`dmy_hms`) in real data is not matching. May be you need to share few samples having different date/time formats from your data.

Answer (score 0):

A solution can be achieved using `tidyr:unite` function along with `dplyr` and `lubridate` packages.

The main approach is to find a way to `group` on continuous appearance of `Yes` and `No` in condition column.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(lubridate)

data1 %>% unite("DateTime", f_device_time_date, Time.stamp, sep = " ") %>%
  mutate(DateTime = dmy_hms(DateTime)) %>%
  mutate(Condition = as.character(Condition)) %>%
  mutate(grp = cumsum(Condition != lag(Condition, default = " "))) %>%
  group_by(Date = date(DateTime), grp, Condition) %>%
  filter(Condition == "No") %>%
  summarise(MaxCountofNo = n()) %>%
  group_by(Date) %>%
  filter(MaxCountofNo == max(MaxCountofNo)) %>%
  select(Date, MaxCountofNo)

# # A tibble: 1 x 2
# # Groups: Date [1]
#         Date       MaxCountofNo
#       <date>            <int>
#   1 2017-02-01            4
```

The data from OP has got records for only 1 day but my solution will work on data with multiple dates.

The above solution calculates maximum number of consecutive `No` for a day. Perhaps that's what OP intend to have.